# Save to Core Data - one-to-many relationship in a loop

Tags: swift, loops, core-data, save, relationship

I have two entities in Core Data. MyMonth and MyPage.
Each month have many pages, so there is to-many relationship between them. When I save, update, delete, it works fine. If I try to save in a loop,  it only saves once (or overwriting maybe).
Here data model :

[image]
[image]

I fetch pages from firebase, it fetches perfectly. After getting all pages, I run my code for saving them to Core Data, like this:

```
func saveBackupPages(firebasePages : [PageModel], savingHandler: @escaping (_ success : Bool) -> Void){
       guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
           print("error")
           return
       }
             
       for singlePage in firebasePages {
           let selectedMonth = MyMonth(context: context)
           let selectedPage = MyPage(context: context)

           selectedMonth.name = singlePage.date.getFormattedDate(format: "MMyyyy")
           selectedMonth.userID = FirebaseAuthService.instance.storedUserId
               selectedPage.id = singlePage.id
               selectedPage.body = singlePage.body
               selectedPage.date = singlePage.date
               selectedPage.isFull = singlePage.isFull
               selectedPage.isMarked = singlePage.isMarked
               selectedPage.pic1URL = singlePage.picURL1
               selectedPage.pic2URL = singlePage.picURL2
               selectedPage.pic3URL = singlePage.picURL3
               selectedPage.version = singlePage.version
               selectedMonth.addToPages(selectedPage)
       }
       do {
           try context.save()
           savingHandler(true)
           print("New page created in core data")
       } catch let error {
           print(error)
           savingHandler(false)
       }
   }
```

When I do this it saves only one page per month. For example if I try to save 4 pages to two months, (2 pages for each month), it only saves 1 page for each month. If I save 20 page for one month, it again only saves one page. So relationship works but I think it overwriting pages in a month.

I also get these lines out of the loop :

```
let selectedMonth = MyMonth(context: context)
let selectedPage = MyPage(context: context)
```

Didn't fix anything. I am very new to core data relationships. What should I do to fix it?

Edit : First, thanks @Joakim Danielson for advice. I did it :

```
    func saveBackupPages(firebasePases : [PageModel], savingHandler: @escaping (_ success : Bool) -> Void){
        guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        
        let months = [String: MyMonth]()
        
        for singlePage in firebasePases {
            let month = singlePage.date.getFormattedDate(format: "MMyyyy")
            let selectedMonth: MyMonth
            if let existingMonth = months[month] {
                selectedMonth = existingMonth
            } else {
                selectedMonth = MyMonth(context: context)
                selectedMonth.name = month
                selectedMonth.userID = FirebaseAuthService.instance.storedUserId
            }

            let selectedPage = MyPage(context: context)
            selectedPage.id = singlePage.id
            selectedPage.body = singlePage.body
            selectedPage.date = singlePage.date
            selectedPage.isFull = singlePage.isFull
            selectedPage.isMarked = singlePage.isMarked
            selectedPage.pic1URL = singlePage.picURL1
            selectedPage.pic2URL = singlePage.picURL2
            selectedPage.pic3URL = singlePage.picURL3
            selectedPage.version = singlePage.version
            selectedMonth.addToPages(selectedPage)
        }
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            savingHandler(true)
            print("New page created in core data")
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately didn't worked, or maybe I misunderstood what to do.  I used same month with 4 pages. It only saved one page. So I changed my function. Now for each page and month, my function first fetches result and decide if the page / month exist or not, then save it if page don't exist in core data. It works, but not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating a new instance of `MyMonth` for each  `singlePage` object and adds a single `MyPage` object to that month.

What you need to do is to maintain a local cache so that you can lookup and reuse existing `MyMonth` objects when they exist for a month ("MMyyyy").

We do this by creating a local dictionary to hold the `MyMonth` objects.

```
var months = [String: MyMonth]()
```

Then at the top of the `for` loop we extract the current month and use it as the key to check if we have a `MyMonth` object or if we need to create a new one

```
for singlePage in firebasePages {
    let month = singlePage.date.getFormattedDate(format: "MMyyyy")
    let selectedMonth: MyMonth
    if let existingMonth = months[month] {
        selectedMonth = existingMonth
    } else {
        selectedMonth = MyMonth(context: context)
        selectedMonth.name = month
        selectedMonth.userID = FirebaseAuthService.instance.storedUserId
    }
   // rest of the code in the loop is the same
}
```

You could clean up the code a little by creating a new object in a function

```
func make(month: String) -> MyMonth {
    let newMonth = MyMonth(context: context)
    newMonth.name = month
    newMonth.userID = FirebaseAuthService.instance.storedUserId
    return newMonth
}
```

then the code above in the loop could be written in a much shorter way

```
for singlePage in firebasePages {
    let month = singlePage.date.getFormattedDate(format: "MMyyyy")
    let selectedMonth = months[month, default: make(month: month)]
   // rest of the code in the loop is the same
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Joakim Danielson. I will try this and reply here.

Comment: I add my feedback as en edit to my question. It didn't worked unfortunately. So I returned to my old implementation. But from your code, I got the idea and I will refactor my code later. I will mark your answer as the most helpful. Thank you. @Joakim Danielson